# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing en aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicacion que usa una funcion en Java script y envia una llamada para consumir un servicio web.

Todo funciona bien pero no se me aficha nada en el navegador.

Cuando veo la consola me aparece un mesaje `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`

He tratado de buscar en varios lados pero no tengo respuesta. Alguna idea

El codigo esta hecho en C# y aspx

Comment: podrías publicar el código que estas haciendo por parte del server?

Comment: Hola @A arancibia, ¿tu controlas el servicio web?, es decir ¿puedes modificarlo para agregar el header que indica Marco en su respuesta?

Answer (score 3):

Hay un sitio dedicado a brindar información sobre **CORS** para cualquier tecnología. En tu caso como mencionas que usas servicios web de ASP supongo que la información que te será útil es referente al IIS7: http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Dándole un vistazo rápido, tendrás que modificar tu **web.config** (en donde están tus servicios web) para incluir la siguiente información.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Efectue las modificaciones y me aparece siempre el mismo mensaje de error. Remplaze mi web.config por el que me dijiste de hacer pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Si el pedido que haces desde la página con JavaScript es a otro dominio, no podrás hacerlo por la [cross-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Lo que te indica el error es que indicando el header HTTP Access-Control-Allow-Origin en el pedido de origen de la página en sí, podrás consumir un web service en otro dominio.

Si la página está en ejemplo.com y el pedido se hace a servicio.com , en el servidor ejemplo.com debes agregar un header HTTP que sea

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: servicio.com
```

En cualquier motor de servidor web se puede agregar un header HTTP sin mucha dificultad.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta a menos que puedas incluir algo de código que muestre como incluir el header usando la tecnología especificada en la pregunta

Comment: No entendiste la respuesta, no se usa código en estos casos para arreglar el problema, se realiza una configuración a nivel servidor web. No se la tecnología web que está utilizando por lo que no puedo indicar cómo incluir el header

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo el OP indica que está usando C# y asp.net. Y si existen varias maneras de hacer que el response resutlante tenga el Header correspondiente por código.

Comment: Pero no es la mejor solución, porque son configuraciones que es mejor hacerlas en el servidor web debido a que esto presta muchísima más flexibilidad en la implementación y abstiene al código de manejar una lógica que el servidor web está diseñado para manejar. No voy a escribir una respuesta que me parezca una solución mediocre, y no todo es sobre código siempre.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo No se trata de código, se trata de ayudar al OP a buscar una solución a su problema. Esta es la razón por la que en SOes escribimos las respuestas, para ayudar a otros desarrolladores como tu a resolver los problemas del día a día. Al menos pon un ejemplo de como sería esa configuración aunque no lo sepas tus respuestas puede ayudar a muchos

Comment: Hay cientos de posibles servidores web, no se cual utilizará por lo que no puedo indicar qué método usar, y voy a dejar de discutir sobre la naturaleza de SO y mi respuesta, si no les gusta vote down y listo.

Comment: En esos casos lo mejor es preguntar al OP antes de responder o dejar en la respuesta varias opciones para que el OP elija. Igual yo pienso que eesta es una buena respuesta aunque se puede mejorar. Aunque de nada servirá si no tiene control sobre el servicio. Por eso es mejor preguntar antes de responder algo que no aplique